# Is series uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Summation $$\sum_n \frac{ 2n a_n x^n(1-x)}{1+x^{2n}}$$ Where $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent series of real numbers.

Comment: Hard to read. ${}{}$

Comment: What have you tried?